# ping6: sendmsg: Operation not supported on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ipv6

I'm trying to set up IPv6 on FreeBSD 8.2.

I added to the /etc/rc.conf the following lines:

```
ipv6_enable="YES"
ipv6_gateway_enable="YES"
ipv6_ifconfig_le0="ff00::2"
```

and restarted IPv6:

```
/etc/rc.d/network_ipv6 restart
```

Now I have the following settings for network interfaces:

```
le0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 00:50:56:01:04:87
    inet 10.76.247.78 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.76.247.255
    inet6 ff00::2 prefixlen 64 
    nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
le1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 00:50:56:01:04:86
    media: Ethernet autoselect
    status: active
plip0: flags=8851<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=3<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV>
```

And now I'm trying to ping. "ping6 ::1" is successful, but "ping6 ff00::2" writes the following errors:

```
# ping6 ff00::2
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) ff00::2 --> ff00::2
ping6: sendmsg: Operation not supported
ping6: wrote ff00::2 16 chars, ret=-1
ping6: sendmsg: Operation not supported
ping6: wrote ff00::2 16 chars, ret=-1
```

What have I done wrong? What does this error mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `ff00::2` address to an interface which is illegal because it is a multicast address and you can only set unicast addresses on an interface.

Besides, `ff00::2` has a reserved scope as per [RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291), so it is also illegal.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't know. I've changed the address to F001::2. It works now.